# Show that the sequence $a_1 = 0, a_{n+1} = \sqrt{5+2a_n}$ converges and find the limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Show that this sequence converges and find the limit.
$a_1 = 0$, $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{5+2a_{n} }$

Comment: Hint: If the limit exists, it is a fixed point of $x \mapsto \sqrt{5 + 2x}$.

Answer (score 10):

Suppose that we’ve shown — somehow — that the sequence converges to some limit $L$. Finding $L$ is then quite easy. Let $f(x)=\sqrt{5+2x}$; then $f$ is a continuous function on its domain, so

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)=f(L)\;.$$

This is an argument that you’ll see over and over in problems of this and related kinds. Solve the equation $L=f(L)$ for $L$: it’s $L=\sqrt{5+2L}$, so $L^2=5+2L$, and after a little algebra we find that $L=1\pm\sqrt6$. Clearly $a_n\ge 0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$; why? This means that the sequence cannot possibly have a negative limit, so if it has any limit at all, that limit must be $L=1+\sqrt6$.

One of the standard ways to show that a sequence converges is to show that it’s both monotone and bounded.

- Show that if $0\le x<1+\sqrt6$, then $x<f(x)$. This is an easy exercise in quadratic inequalities.
- Show that if $0\le x<1+\sqrt6$, then $0<f(x)<1+\sqrt6$. One way is to show that $f$ is a strictly increasing function of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

For convergence, show that $\displaystyle\left|\sqrt{5+2(a_n+\delta)}-a_n\right|<\delta$ for sufficiently small delta and $a_n$ close to the limit. The limit is given by $\displaystyle a=\sqrt{5+2a}$, $a>0$ (since $a_1>0$ and $a_{n+1}$ has the same sign as $a_n$ thereafter) or $\displaystyle a=1+\sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

To show that the sequence $\{a\}_{n\geq 1}$ does converge to some limit $L$, I shall show that actually, the function $f:\mathbb{R^+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $f(x)=\sqrt{5+2x}$, is a contraction on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and hence it has at least one fixed point $L>0$. Then by the argument @Brian M. Scott provided, we have $L=1+\sqrt{6}$.

To show that $f$ is a contraction on $\mathbb{R}^+$, let, for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R^+},\ $ $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$. Then $$d_2(x,y)=\frac{2d_1(x,y)}{|\sqrt{5+2x}+\sqrt{5+2y}|}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}d_1(x,y)$$ So, by definition, $f$ is a contraction and hence $L>0$ exists.$\hspace{6cm} \ \Box$